# Navigation withing folder structure

Tags: php, html

In the folder for my website I have the files index.php and nav.php and in the same folder as the index.php and nav.php file I have another folder called "pages". In the pages folder I have the files products.php and faq.php

Now, I use the include_once function to insert the navigation from the file nav.php into the files index.php, products.php and faq.php.

Below is the code from my navigation:

```
<nav>

    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $base; ?>/website/index.php">Home</a></li>      
    </ul>

    <ul>    
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $base; ?>/website/pages/products.php">Produkte</a>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $base; ?>/website/pages/faq.php"> FAQ </a>
    </li>
    </ul>   

</nav>
```

As you can see right now I am using fixed links with a php-variable.
The variable refers to

?php $base="http://localhost";?>

I use the variable with the fixed link because when I would enter the code:

href=../pages/faq.php"> FAQ

the browser can't find this page when I am in that moment on the index.php because from the index.php the link would be:

href=pages/faq.php"> FAQ

However, if I use this link I will have a problem once I will be on the faq.php page and want to go back to the index.php page.

To solve this issue I am right now using the above mentioned fixed link.

However, is there any way to get rid of the fixed part?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: You can have `./pages/bla.php` which will be relative to the current URL.
While having a variable to hold the website's url is also a good practice (absolute urls)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `include` in place of `include_once`.

The `include_once()` statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the `include()` statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again.

As the name suggests, it will be included just once.